# Chunked Response With HttpResult

Tags: rest, servicestack

When building out a ServiceStack service, we noticed that the responses are almost identical, except that the HttpResult returns a chunked encoding response.

When using the HttpResult object like this:

```
return new HttpResult("0", ContentType.PlainText, HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

we see a response in Fiddler like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3.954 Win32NT/.NET
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 20 Jun 2013 13:33:17 GMT
```

But when using the Response property like this:

```
Response.ContentType = ContentType.PlainText;
Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.OK;
return "1";
```

we see a response in Fiddler like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3.954 Win32NT/.NET
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 20 Jun 2013 14:38:39 GMT
Content-Length: 1
```

We'd like to use the `HttpResult` version as that seems to be much cleaner, but need for it to not be encoded. It appears to be chunking the response whenever adding the responseBody object. When that is taken away, the encoding is removed. However, even explicitly setting the `AllowsPartialResponse` to false does not fix this.

Answer (score 1):

If you submit a pull-request with the correct behaviour covered by tests it will get merged pretty quickly.